# Finding the lower and upper sums of $f(x)=2x+1$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, riemann-sum

I'm trying to find the upper and lower sums for $f(x)=2x+1$ on the interval $[1,4]$.

$P_6$ is the partition of $[1,4]$ consisting of 7 equally space points, $1, \frac{3}{2}, 2, \frac{5}{2},3,\frac{7}{2},4$

So my goal is to find $U(f,P_6)$ and $L(f,P_6)$

Without entering all of my steps I found $U(f,P_6)$ using the following:

I used the fact that $\Delta x=\frac{3}{n}$ and $f(x_i)=2\left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)+1$

When I put them together I get:

$U(f,P_6)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(2\left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)+1\right)\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)=\frac{3(8n+6)}{2n}$

And for the lower sum I put together the following:

$L(f,P_6)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(2\left(\frac{3i}{n}-\frac{3}{n}\right)+1\right)\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)=\frac{3(4n-3)}{n}$

Did I go about this the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=2x+1$ which is increasing function on $[1,4]$ and 
$P_6={1,\frac{3}{2},2,\frac{5}{2},3,\frac{7}{2},4}$ are subdivision.
$I_1=[1,\frac{3}{2}],I_2=[\frac{3}{2},2],I_3=[2,\frac{5}{2}],I_4=[\frac{5}{2},3],I_5=[3,\frac{7}{2}],I_6=[\frac{7}{2},4]$
each interval has length $\frac{1}{2}$
 So,

$|I_k|=\frac{1}{2} \forall k=1,2,\dots,6 $

Now using the subdivision of $[1,4]$. calculate $m[f,I_k]$  and $M[f,I_k]$

then use 
Now calculate

$m[f;I_1]=m[f;1]=2(1)+1=3 $         ;$  M[f;I_1]=M[f;\frac{3}{2} ]=2(\frac{3}{2})+1=4 $

$m[f;I_2]=m[f;\frac{3}{2}]=2(\frac{3}{2})+1=4$  ;
$M[f;I_2]=M[f;2]=2(2)+1=5$

$m[f;I_3]=m[f;2]=2(2)+1=5$ ;
$M[f;I_3]=M[f;\frac{5}{2}]=2(\frac{5}{2})+1=6$

$m[f;I_4]=m[f;\frac{5}{2}]=2(\frac{5}{2})+1=6$;
$M[f;I_4]=M[f;3]=2(3)+1=7$

$m[f;I_5]=m[f;3]=2(3)+1=7$;
$M[f;I_5]=M[f;\frac{7}{2}]=2(\frac{7}{2})+1=8$

$m[f;I_6]=m[f;\frac{7}{2}]=2(\frac{7}{2})+1=8$
$M[f;I_6]=M[f;4]=2(4)+1=9$

$L[f,P_6]=\sum_{k=1}^{6}m[f,I_k]|I_k|=\frac{1}{2}\{3+4+5+6+7+8\}=\frac{33}{2}$

$U[f,P_6]=\sum_{k=1}^{6}M[f,I_k]|I_k|=\frac{1}{2}\{4+5+6+7+8+9\}=\frac{39}{2}$

Comment: So instead of $I_k=\frac{3}{n}$ I should be using $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Oh I see, it's the same thing.  Because $\frac{3}{n}=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: It looks like my work is correct, I just need to plug in $6$ for $n$

Comment: okay note that when you take upper sum you sum up from 1 to infinity , and when you take lower sum you sum you sum up from 1 to n.

Comment: which is wrong.Look in the book Methods of Real Analysis
Textbook by Richard R. Goldberg.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo, for both I'm taking it to $n$

Comment: Oh man... I see the simplicity now when the subdivisions are used.  I just take left endpoints and plug them into my function for lower sums, and then do the same for the right end points for upper sums, and then sum them respectively.